# Intel HAXM's intelhaxm-android.exe is not running

Tags: intel, haxm

after downloading `intel HAXM` i go forward to install it from `C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager` and when i start the setup  `intelhaxm-android.exe` it start and just disappear without giving any error and leaving me in this unfinished situation.
whats the problem? please help!

Comment: i also tried run as admin but the same response(no response).

Comment: i am using intel celeron 1017U @ 1.60 GHz processor and window-8, 64 bit operating system.

Comment: To verify HAXM is running, type `sc query intelhaxm` into the command prompt. If you  get an error, then HAXM is probably not installed correctly.

Comment: BUT the main problem is that the installation process doesnt even started as mentioned when i tried to open the intelhaxm-android.exe for installation it pops up and disappear just in a second.i dnt understand why!

Comment: What if you run the .exe manually via command prompt - do you get any error message? Do you have VT-x enabled in (BIOS/UEFI)? By my experience, it is usually disabled by default. Hyper-V, VirtualBox etc. can also interfere with VT-x.

Comment: yes i also did  it via cmd but the same thing happens..VT-x is enabled by default when checked it in BIOS settings.and  Hyper-V is also disabled.

Comment: this HAXM bundled with other files too one of them is silent_install.bat. is there any possibility that this is related to this issue?.